# Existence of solution to prescribed curvature problem with given asymptotic on the punctured unit disc

Tags: harmonic-analysis, curvature, geometric-analysis

I have trouble understanding a conclusion in the following paper: [Prescribed Curvature and Singularities of Conformal Metrics on Riemann Surfaces by Robert C. McOwen](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272578/1-s2.0-S0022247X00X01746/1-s2.0-S0022247X83712588/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEP7%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIHsieKRPgfes%2FTmcn7Xjr7g2re0QMW7LTui2vMomSqxSAiEAhwjqZSeJoKO%2FX4vif64BgcVXGY3Rone9EB3iwhpyu0oqsgUIFxAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDFugmRoTdyRTnvwswSqPBaD10gLn5WckkXmkt4t3Y45ViI%2BLj%2BZ5mlJw7LxlakB%2BprrbRhMwAQv43AWq7033OJkjP3CPR6YR%2FaXlVYuVDy6Lzraz19ilSFWbt0hxaIZmpYZnEpzBc4zGkBP%2FGWMr6IEbkN7JStkkbv0%2FQKaqdAmAqPGK0dwp9K3zXX2CLrQw1haXE2p4N%2B3TQ4kMYqMEwJ373rusLE7zfaMV125V%2F%2Bz%2BAWpNBa6Ayhp33iosC2wstdGtA%2Bl3LD27rDoJx1Yxar4x6Af4HLihv2pdmdLGLylsOZLmhWXiISd6h6e9D6LmZu5sl2l%2B%2FQjqXD9J12oc7p3C03gM5WHcM0p65GG%2Bp3xCPHP8S4rMA186y32q2NZeEc09UhML9gQDEGFdtxusiDisMAO7nQIC7SUtcNEy0%2BOMJh6vuGoGES9F7hqitHWVnGyqaeFZvopV%2BsQKUbo9Q9w1XDk3NTwwVIDUE9RdtCL7gf2cRB%2FkoR2TIpI4jUaK0YkHuMaj2fgFpoCBFKTpWgk5n65uzozgLZaUYlpncamfihwQL2YzGYVcSMHWuC8x8Myu9Ab2HHSj%2BOa7UYYMjEUwykNAWAm0r6%2Bq9vu9KRVeWJfAECJwI702WD1e8pb%2Flc5Jha8Xuuj0LXCRzYeDJPBbYRxxHG7zv00tVgs4fPTRsLeoS0KMQn5Emb7FBye0FeI%2F7%2FjHTCAjcJxC2xYlmM6%2Bv1Oz%2Fp7BvWJXNsoW756b9M9b%2B5AeqsCEryfbTFLHrgetz6D8OizX7JRpjcp264gFkaDMSsJsUfR2XSjetbOmGImIZWtVDV8qY1rwkTvQzlCTC60rKAXCv2kq7%2Fv%2FCgbD2ic7GVMLLccOWpGSp9rqHqQbFFvcL2oCOQEs%2BCcwjYvUogY6sQEU%2F1eubcG7fw5zdyD54xD2DPV1ROCtiWhNWwRFtfB9XqeIAk3n%2F7B9IpSzyL95ZykMyazaHInxLoXyhm7QQyFDvo7eik3yaUAPpAg9QE%2FGwCJTN3N05DzFcyJORFjHAcRP3ySQaqtv2wFfljfZDlTk67hzvHy0hNixp6uQ179ZCP3Feklj3oCBGSlbNkOCRs%2FW6PegonOHMsnC9pGLUAN2qlbmOutV2gBgqEuPWPc9YFM%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230505T142232Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYRSK6U3D3%2F20230505%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=3fe651b594babfdff79d050ca634b20ed60303edb7f9b3d180ab2b2df19494dc&hash=c1bef07d1b0a290adfd9c7ad68c7ed147b6fef9b1d3856087f2a98bbabccccc1&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022247X83712588&tid=spdf-beb29666-4ace-4b8d-9265-b914adaec0e8&sid=c352a5ca137b704af85a560666aba4f6e544gxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=020359055c5a055d075a&rr=7c29a2d9ff0f4541&cc=de)

In the appendix, part B, we are deriving asymptotic estimates for solutions of the *prescribed curvature problem* or *Kazdan-Warner-Equation*

$$(*)_0\quad \Delta u + \tilde{K} e^{2u} = 0$$

on the punctured unit disc $\{z \in \mathbb C : 0 < |z| < 1\}$ for some non-positive function $\tilde K$. In particular we are considering the case that $C_1 \leq -\tilde K \leq C_2$ for constants $0 < C_1 < C_2$.

The argument goes as follows: Assume there exists a solution u of $(*)_0$ which is continuous on $|z|=1$ and denote with $m_1 = \min\{u(z) : |z|=1\}$ and $m_2 = \max\{u(z) : |z|=1\}$ the minimum and maximum of $u$ on the unit circle. Analysis of the related ODEs

$$(*)_i\quad Y'' + Y'/r = C_ie^{2Y}$$

for $i =1,2$ shows that there exist unique solutions $Y_i$ of $(*)_i$ with initial condition $Y_i(1) = m_i$ and prescribed asymtotic behavior

$$Y_i(r) = \log \frac 1 r - \log \log \frac 1 r +o(1) \quad \text{as} \quad r \to 0.$$

It can be shown that $Y_1(r) \leq Y_2(r)$ for all $r \in (0,1)$, so we may think of $Y_1$ as a lower barrier and $Y_2$ as an upper barrier of sorts (?).
From this condition, which is called $(B.8)$ in the paper, it is claimed that there must exist a solution $U$ of $(*)_0$ with the same initial conditions as $u$ and asymptotic behavior like $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, more precisely

$$U(z) = \log \frac 1 {|z|} - \log \log \frac 1 {|z|} +O(1)\quad \text{as} \quad |z| \to 0$$
$$U(z) = u(z) \quad \text{for all} \quad |z|=1.$$

This is the point I am having trouble to understand. I do not see how to construct such a solution $U$. As it is written in the paper it should follow immediately from some general principle.